# How to set width of view with respect to value in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

How to change the second view length according to value. If the first one value is 100 then the width is match_parent. If the second one value is 60 then how to set the width of that according to that one.

```
             <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/headerproject">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/grey">
                    
                </View>
                
                <View
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    >
                    
                </View>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not use `ProgressBar`. Try using ProgressBar

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But I want to show a value that out of 100, 60 is completed. This is not progress. It will only reflect the count.

Comment: If you don't want to use Progress Bar, use a Contraint layout with percent width.

Comment: can you please give an example with some code how to achieve that one.

Comment: @Nayan is there any option in Progressbar,How I will set a value on progress bar

Comment: You can set value on ProgressBar like this `progressBar.setProgress(value)`

Comment: how I will show this value  below to the bar in the proper position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ProgressBar` but if you really need to go on this way, you can set the green bar width like:

```
View viewGray, viewGreen;
int currentValue, totalValue;
//Some relevant code
viewGray.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int parentWith = viewGray.getWidth();
                int viewGrayWith = parentWith * (currentValue/(float)totalValue);
                viewGreen.getLayoutParams().width = viewGrayWith;
            }
        },50);
```

Comment: int parentWith = viewGray.getWidth(); This always return 0 as parentwidth

Comment: It is because it takes a while for a `view` to be drawn on the screen. Edited my answer. Check it now. @JanardanDash